# How can I use bash command to move a set of directories from one location to another

Tags: command-line, bash

When using the command line I can use

```
for i in *txt; do mv "$i" /home/some_user/some_folder/"$i"; done
```

to move a group of files.

How can I move all directories in the current directory using this same type of command?

Comment: Actually I think information on how to move all directories in a folder as well as only certain directories would be helpful for in the future. Though at the moment I'm just trying to move all directories in a certain folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a condition to check if the item is a folder.

```
for i in *; do
  if [ -d "$i" ] ; then
    mv "$i" /home/some_user/some_folder/"$i"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Of course, adjust the wildcard to fit your need, filtering all folders ending by txt doesn't really make sense.

Comment: There's no need to glob and *then* check for directories here. See the first alternative in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

### With shell “glob” [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching)

```
mv -t /home/some_user/some_folder -- */
```

- `-t` instructs `mv` to move all listed objects into the directory denoted by the path following `-t`.
- `*/` matches and is expanded to the names of all (non-hidden) directories in the current directory. Note the final `/` that restricts the glob matches to directories! (If you need to include hidden file names starting with a `.`, enable the `dotglob` option with `shopt -s dotglob`.)

### With [`find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/index.html)

```
find . -minepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec mv -t /home/some_user/some_folder -- {} +
```

- `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` restricts the search to the content of the given directory (here: `.`).
- `-type d` restricts the matches to directories. This includes hidden directories; to exclude them use `! -name '.*'`.
- `-exec COMMAND [ARGUMENTS...] {} +` runs `COMMAND` with `ARGUMENTS...` (if any) and appends the paths of all matched files.